# JavaHTTPServer Get contents of (html) textbox on (html) button click

Tags: java, html, com.sun.net.httpserver

my question is how to get the contents of a textbox in my javahttpserver webinterface

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Message - Send</title>
</head>
<body>

<input id="message" type="text"/>
<button id="message_send" type="button">Send</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Do I need to do it via javascript or java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this function with jquery in it when the button is pushed. (I put an alert function in it so you can test it) 
Make sure you include the jquery.js

```
function getstuff(){
    var box = $("#textboxtarget").val();
    alert(box);
}
```

Comment: oh ok but how can I use it in my JavaApplication?

Comment: So you're not doing a web page?

Comment: I am doing a webpage in my JavaHTTPServer and I need to get the contents of a Textbox in Java

Comment: Oh, yeah, so that should work. What are you planning on doing with it?

Comment: So I am using an API (Java) for my Teamspeak 3 Server and I want to make a WebInterface to do some actions (e.g. sending messages to the server)

Comment: Oh ok, well, I don't know any coding stuff for Teamspeak

Comment: ok but it solved my problem (my httpserver can use arguments and i just created a new site and gave the arguments.

Comment: OK :). Glad I could help